# Python time optimisation of for loop using newaxis

Tags: python, time, for-loop, numpy

I need to calculate n number of points(3D) with equal spacing along a defined line(3D).
I know the starting and end point of the line. First, I used

```
for k in range(nbin):
  step = k/float(nbin-1)
  bin_point.append(beam_entry+(step*(beamlet_intersection-beam_entry)))
```

Then, I found that using append for large arrays takes more time, then I changed code like this:

```
bin_point = [start_point+((k/float(nbin-1))*(end_point-start_point)) for k in range(nbin)]
```

I got a suggestion that using newaxis will further improve the time.
The modified code looks like this.

```
step      = arange(nbin) / float(nbin-1)
bin_point = start_point + ( step[:,newaxis,newaxis]*((end_pint - start_point))[newaxis,:,:] )
```

But, I could not understand the newaxis function, I also have a doubt that, whether the same code will work if the structure or the shape of the start_point and end_point are changed. Similarly how can I use the newaxis to mdoify the following code

```
 for j in range(32):      # for all los
   line_dist[j] = sqrt([sum(l) for l in (end_point[j]-start_point[j])**2])
```

Sorry for being so clunky, to be more clear the structure of the start_point and end_point are

```
array([ [[1,1,1],[],[],[]....[]], 
        [[],[],[],[]....[]],
        [[],[],[],[]....[]]......,
        [[],[],[],[]....[]] ])
```

Comment: What type are `start_point` etc. of?  How do I create one?

Comment: @Alfe As I have defined all the points are 3 Dimensional, a single start_point or end_point looks like this [1,2,3], I get these points as inputs. So, In the code above a start_point or end_point is essentially a collection of points like [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[4,5,3]]. I have tried to explain this in the last part of my question namely, 'array'. Sorry about this, I have made the nested lists to use array operation, which greatly reduce the time.

Comment: So `start_point` actually is a list of points, not a single point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation of the newaxis version in the question: these are *not* matrix multiplies, ndarray multiply is element-by-element multiply with [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  step[:,newaxis,newaxis] is num_steps x 1 x 1 and point[newaxis,:,:] is 1 x num_points x num_dimensions.  Broadcasting together ndarrays with shape (num_steps x 1 x 1) and (1 x num_points x num_dimensions) will work, because the broadcasting rules are that every dimension should be either 1 or the same; it just means "repeat the array with dimension 1 as many times as the corresponding dimension of the other array".  This results in an ndarray with shape (num_steps x num_points x num_dimensions) in a very efficient way; the i, j, k subscript will be the k-th coordinate of the i-th step along the j-th line (given by the j-th pair of start and end points).

Walkthrough:

```
>>> start_points = numpy.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]])
>>> end_points = numpy.array([[10, 0, 0], [0, 10, 0]])
>>> steps = numpy.arange(10)/9.0
>>> start_points.shape
(2, 3)
>>> steps.shape
(10,)
>>> steps[:,numpy.newaxis,numpy.newaxis].shape
(10, 1, 1)
>>> (steps[:,numpy.newaxis,numpy.newaxis] * start_points).shape
(10, 2, 3)
>>> (steps[:,numpy.newaxis,numpy.newaxis] * (end_points - start_points)) + start_points
array([[[  1.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   1.,   0.]],
       [[  2.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   2.,   0.]],
       [[  3.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   3.,   0.]],
       [[  4.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   4.,   0.]],
       [[  5.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   5.,   0.]],
       [[  6.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   6.,   0.]],
       [[  7.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   7.,   0.]],
       [[  8.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   8.,   0.]],
       [[  9.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   9.,   0.]],
       [[ 10.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,  10.,   0.]]])
```

As you can see, this produces the correct answer :)  In this case broadcasting (10,1,1) and (2,3) results in (10,2,3).  What you had is broadcasting (10,1,1) and (1,2,3) which is exactly the same and also produces (10,2,3).

The code for the distance part of the question does not need newaxis: the inputs are num_points x num_dimensions, the ouput is num_points, so one dimension has to be removed.  That is actually the axis you sum along.  This should work:

```
line_dist = numpy.sqrt( numpy.sum( (end_point - start_point) ** 2, axis=1 )
```

Here numpy.sum(..., axis=1) means sum along that axis only, rather than all elements: a ndarray with shape num_points x num_dimensions summed along axis=1 produces a result with num_points, which is correct.

EDIT: removed code example without broadcasting.
EDIT: fixed up order of indexes.
EDIT: added line_dist

Comment: I hope that you are trying to create a matrix by using the transpose, if it is so, the newaxis method defined in the question will be more efficient. Because, my main worry is about the time. Since, the calculation is needed for a 500 or 1000 sets of 1280 pair of start and end points.(may increase). That is the array part defined in my question has 1280 3D points in one row/line and the array has 500 or 1000(is nbin)

Comment: @Alissham: there is no matrix multiply, these are no matrixes.  Matrix multiply is ndarray.dot().  This is element-by-element multiply with *broadcasting* which simply replicates the input arrays along a dimension.  In this case, the steps gets replicated along the dimensions of both number of points and number of coordinates in a point.  The two key parts are (1) this is entirely element-by-element (unlike matrix multiply), and (2) arrays get replicated as needed.

Comment: @Alissham: please remember to accept the answer above if it works for you, or let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still couldn't get how to generate 'n' number of points(bin_points). For line_dist tat's cool to use and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not through understanding all you wrote, but some things I already can tell you; maybe they help.

`newaxis` is rather a marker than a function (in fact, it is plain `None`).  It is used to add an (unused) dimension to a multi-dimensional value.  With it you can make a 3D value out of a 2D value (or even more).  Each dimension already there in the input value must be represented by a colon `:` in the index (assuming you want to use all values, otherwise it gets complicated beyond our usecase), the dimensions to be added are denoted by `newaxis`.

Example:
input is a one-dimensional vector (1D): 1,2,3
output shall be a matrix (2D).
There are two ways to accomplish this; the vector could fill the lines with one value each, or the vector could fill just the first and only line of the matrix.  The first is created by `vector[:,newaxis]`, the second by `vector[newaxis,:]`.  Results of this:

```
>>> array([ 7,8,9 ])[:,newaxis]
array([[7],
       [8],
       [9]])
>>> array([ 7,8,9 ])[newaxis,:]
array([[7, 8, 9]])
```

(Dimensions of multi-dimensional values are represented by nesting of arrays of course.)

If you have more dimensions in the input, use the colon more than once (otherwise the deeper nested dimensions are simply ignored, i.e. the arrays are treated as simple values).  I won't paste a representation of this here as it won't clarify things due to the optical complexity when 3D and 4D values are written on a 2D display using nested brackets.  I hope it gets clear anyway.

Comment: So, newaxis code part in the question is essentially a 3D matrix multiplication rather than a normal vector multiplication. If, I am correct, then what i used is a matrix multiplication of nx3 * 3x1, which gives the result as nx1.

Answer (score 0):

The newaxis reshapes the array in such a way so that when you multiply numpy uses broadcasting. [Here is a good tutorial on broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

`step[:, newaxis, newaxis]` is the same as `step.reshape((step.shape[0], 1, 1))` (if `step` is 1d). Either method for reshaping should be very fast because reshaping arrays in numpy is very cheep, it just makes a view of the array, especially because you should only be doing it once.